# Jenkins Console Output character issue, but plain text show correct

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins working with newman command (postman) `newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/631643-f695cab7-6878-eb55-7943-ad88e1ccfd65-JsLv`, and the Console Output shows:
[image: console-output-1]

But when I go to **View as plain text**, the character shows correct:
[image: console-text-output-1]

Here more details:

- Jenkins Version: `2.7.0`
- Job Type: `free style`
- Slave OS: `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`
- Jenkins Installation way: `apt install jenkins`
- JAVA_ARG: `JAVA_ARGS=...  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=utf-8`

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

that is formatting issue
you may try to configure jenkins job to use formatted output as well
check it out https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin
try all available schemes one by one, some of then should works well

Comment: Thanks @Orest, the AnsiColor Plugin has been checked in Jenkins job config.